# Searching a single term from Firefox address bar

Tags: firefox, browser

I've edited keyword.url to my favorite search engine and disabled domain autocomplete, but Firefox still tries to connect to invalid domains when I type a single word in the address bar (like http://foo/ for foo) instead of using my search engine directly. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/) extension has all advanced search features that I need.

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is normal – `foo` may be a valid hostname in the local network or under the same domain (for example, after appending the primary suffix – `home.` or `example.com.` – or by using NetBIOS to resolve it). Even on the Internet, a single-label domain is valid – http://tk./ and the (now dead) http://to./ as examples. Therefore Firefox (and probably all other programs) will always consider one-word addresses as domain names.

---

You can, as a workaround, use keyword search: click the search engines drop-down menu, choose "Edit search engines", then edit your keywords.

[image: Search engines]

Another way is to add a bookmark pointing to your search engine. For example, I have keyword `g` with URL `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s` which I use daily.

[image: Bookmark properties]

Comment: Thank you for the tip of using a bookmark as a workaround.

Comment: "Therefore Firefox (and probably all other programs) will always consider one-word addresses as domain names." Chrome doesn't, which lets you use single-word searches with your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Setting **browser.fixup.alternate.enabled** to false in about:config is supposed to disable domain guessing.  Sadly, Firefox 5.0 still returns the failed DNS request.

Comment: This worked for me in the current version of Firefox (63).